# Recommendation: Building a Windows 10 React-Native application with react-native-windows or reactXP for IOS and Windows apps only

Tags: javascript, react

I've looked around and would like a difinitive explanation of the differences of the 2 products and which would one recommend for the production of a Windows 10 and Ios application.

Here are the 2 git repos

https://github.com/microsoft/reactxp

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows

Comment: I think this is off-topic for this site. Software Recommendations is about finding software that meets your requirements, not about finding out what a given piece of software does.

Comment: Agreed. Users post a list of requirements and we recommend software. We do not compare, as that can lead to opinion-based answers. Voting to close

Answer (score 1):

ReactXP is about sharing more view layer code between web and Android/iOS/Windows. From https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/:

> XP means X-Platform. Share most of your code between the web, iOS, Android, and Windows.
>
> With React and React Native, your web app can share most its logic with your iOS and Android apps, but the view layer needs to be implemented separately for each platform. We have taken this a step further and developed a thin cross-platform layer we call ReactXP. If you write your app to this abstraction, you can share your view definitions, styles and animations across multiple target platforms. Of course, you can still provide platform-specific UI variants, but this can be done selectively where desired.

React Native Windows is an [out-of-tree platform](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/out-of-tree-platforms) that deploys to Windows UWP just like vanilla React Native does with Android and iOS.

If you're only writing for iOS and Windows, with no web, it seems like ReactXP wouldn't be helpful for you.